# How to say this concisely?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am applying for this mainly research position. It might happen that there is a course relevant to my research topic, and in that case I would like to teach that course too. So I am trying to say this in one single sentence, like the following:

> ———-, I would like to teach an introductory course on the topic.

In the blank I like to say this as concise as possible: **if or in case there is such a course in the center or around.**

So I want a phrase like ‘upon request’, but not exactly that, because it might not necessarily be requested of me; I might propose a syllabus and it be accepted.

I want something to mean ‘in case there was such a course’, or ‘in case I could find such a course’.

I think there was a phrase that roughly Has that sense, but I cannot remember it.

Comment: Consider: In case you have sugar, I'd like sugar. Redundant. You get the same point across without any *if*:  Besides research, consider me for teaching an introductory course on the topic.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes but the position is not given directly by the university. A third party evaluate applications and decide who get the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The school curriculum permitting, I'd be willing  to teach an introductory course on the topic.

([ref. Representation Matters: Becoming an anti-racist educator](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Representation_Matters/o5VoEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22curriculum+permitting%22&pg=PT182&printsec=frontcover)) At Key Stage 3, teachers can teach the books that they want (school and English department curriculum permitting).

Answer (score 2):

I get the sense you are asking implying a question and a desire, go with 'if possible'

Answer (score -2):

It appears that the OP is looking for this idiom: "*While somebody is at it*"

According to the *Cambridge Dictionary*, the meaning of the idiom is:

> at the same time as or in addition to doing something else

*I'm contributing to the economy and enjoying myself while I'm at it.*

Comment: Too informal for this context.

Comment: "While somebody is at it" means *if convenient* more than 'if permitted' or 'if available'. Granted that this and many questions suggest a guessing game that may have good answers, but are more a mind reading exercise. So, a flawless answer may get no love for not being the hoped-for one. Just saying.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thank you for pointing out the subtle distinction I didn't take into account while writing this answer. It always feels great to learn from folks like you and others on this wonderful forum. :)